# How can I serve js and css from Drupal 7

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm very new to Drupal and I have a bunch of sites to manage that are in different cms's like wordpress, sharepoint and others. My goal is to merge all the content into drupal over time.

I want to manage a master menu in Drupal and when items are added or removed generate a html code snippet representing the menu that the other sites can pick up from the local file system or via a url if they are not.

How can I serve content from a url without the themes and drupal html being applied?

eg

have this url serve a css file

```
http://localhost/css/global.css
```

or get a js file from

```
http://localhost/js/app.js
```

or from a url like this

```
 http://localhost/globalmenu.html
```

get this html snippet ONLY

```
 <div class="nav">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="">Menu Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu Item 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="">Menu Item 3</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

*** EDIT ***
The answer about the menu hook is really close to what i want, but I think i may have confused things by mentioning menus at all.

So I apologise as I didn't make what I am after very clear. Ill try and reword it.

For an arbitrary url I want to return content of any kind from the drupal 7 cms.

Which 'hook' takes the url, matches it to a pattern, and then allows me to send anything back on the response stream, and how do I change the mime types.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a custom module for this (see the [Module Developer's Guide](http://drupal.org/node/361112) if you're not already familiar with creating modules, it's pretty straightforward).

Once you've got your custom module set up you need to implement [`hook_menu()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) and define a callback function for your URL:

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items['globalmenu.html'] = array(
    'title' => 'Global Menu',
    'access callback' => TRUE, // If you want any source to be able to access this page
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_deliver_global_menu'
  ); 

  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_deliver_global_menu() {
  print '<div class="nav">...';
  drupal_exit();
}
```

Since Drupal will only actually apply the theme wrappers to a page if something is returned from the page callback, simply printing your HTML and calling `drupal_exit()` is all you need to do.

Sorry if some of that is stuff you already know, I thought it best to err on the side of caution.

Comment: thanks you were right to keep it basic...I know nothing. I give this a try right now

Answer (score 1):

There is another simplest way using [hook_preprocess](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7).

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if (!empty($node) && $node->nid == $the_specific_node_id) {
    drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . "/file.js", "theme");
    drupal_add_css(path_to_theme(). "/file.css", "theme");
  }
}
```

Insert this function in your theme's `template.php` file

See theme functions [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7)